# OpenUI5 Input Internationalisation. What's wrong with 2,45?

Tags: sapui5

I am building an internationalized application using OpenUI5 1.28.

The `sap.m.Input` fields for quantity and values are not allowing me to enter the data with a decimal place without using a **"."** notification.

For example: My Firefox browser is set to German, It should allow me to enter `2,45` as a price value in the input field.

If I enter `2.45`, my price is valid. If I enter `2,45`, the input `valueState` is set to "Error"* that should not be happen.

I have checked my locale against the SAPUI5 configuration.

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLanguage();
```

This returns "de", so `2,45` should be valid.

The input field is defined below :

```
<Input id="itemPriceInput" type="Number">
<layoutData>
<l:GridData span="L3 M3 S6" />
</layoutData>
</Input>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Citing from the [docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.InputType.html#.Number):

"sap.m.InputType.Number
A text field for specifying a number. Brings up a number pad keyboard. Specifying an input type of \d* or [0-9]* is equivalent to using this type."

The main purpose of `sap.m.InputType` is to bring up the right keyboard on touch devices. It does not do any validation (btw. if it did both '.' and ',' would be prohibited).

For validation purposes you should use the data binding type system. It perfectly handles I18N as well:

- [API sap.ui.model.type](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type-1.html)
- [Using the Data Binding Type System](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f37e746f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

BR
Chris